# Is writing data to Firebase an asynchronous operation?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I have following two lines of code.

```
FirebaseService.service.createFirebaseUser(uid: (user?.uid)!, userData: picUser.toDictionary()) // creates firebase user with userData

weakSelf?.performSegue(withIdentifier: SEGUES.HOME_SCREEN_TO_TAB_HOME, sender: nil) // go to the next screen
```

Before I perform the segue, I want to make sure that it created a firebase user and updated the data for that user into the Firebase Database. I can't think of a sure way to test if writing to Firebase is asynchronous or not. If you have any prior experience with this and can tell me how writing to Firebase work, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You need to handle this with a  CallBack !If you check the method where you are calling to create the user there should an override with completion block.

Comment: Thanks man.. It's a good start, because I didn't know there would an override method with completion block. I would try when I get to it, and let you know how it goes. Thanks once again.